# Как убрать поля с e-mail, именем пользователя и т. д.?

Tags: django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пользуюсь django-threadedcomments, реализация простая как пять копеек, но у меня есть своя система аккаунтов, и хотелось бы привязать комментарии к ней. Но для начала, мне надо убрать вот эти вот чудесные поля, или чтоб они сами заполнялись за пользователя, но были скрыты от него. Пользуюсь модулем threadedcomments из-за того, что нигде нормально не объясняют, как реализовать многоуровневые комментарии. В документации никаких наводок даже близко не нашел. Главное - помогите узнать, где находится код, который мне нужен, я дальше сам все сделаю
UPD: ещё порылся в доках, там говорят, что каким-то образом можно оверрайднуть их шаблоны, но не написано где они

Answer (score 0):

Удалите из формы те поля которые не хотите получать установив `null=True blank=True`. Затем переопределите форму в представлениях:

**views.py**

```
if form.is_valid():
    comment = form.save(commit=False)
    comment.username = request.user.username
    comment.email = request.user.email # Если почта используется
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я в курсе о том как это реализовать. Меня интересует скорее что переопределять, нежели как. Просто мне нужно знать, что импортировать, что именно переопределять, в каком месте django-threadedcomments находятся переопределяемые форма и шаблон.

Comment: Тогда вам необходимо обратится по пути:
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/threadedcomments
Там имеется и models.py  В котором вы можете убрать нежелательные поля и form.py для удаления зависимостей и views.py.
Проверьте чтоб не осталось зависимостей иначе приведёт к ошибке